# Javafx chart show more empty space

Tags: javafx

I am customizing the javafx charts a bit adding valuelabels etc above bars and sliding out certain parts of piecharts. The problem is some of the extras come outside of the visual area.

Is there a simple way to get piecharts to become smaller (but the chart component itself retain its size so that there is more empty space surround the pie?

The same issue with barcharts. I need more empty space above my vertical bars, and more empty space to the right of my horizontal bars.

All data in the table has Number(mostly BigDeicmal) for its value and String for its key and series.

Comment: Just a guess, but try setting `-fx-padding` on your chart.

Comment: That didn't help, i was able to fix it for barcharts by not using an autoaxis and instead just specifing the min, max and ticksizes myself, but no idea how to solve it on the pie chart

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) so that somebody can replicate your issue.